# Paramterized classes in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, domain-driven-design, value-objects

I'm trying to reduce some boilerplate in a Typescript project using DDD.
My goal is to have a quick way to make a strongly typed Value Object where the only value is a string with a bounded length.

My first attempt was this:

```js
type BoundedStringProps = {
  value: string;
};

export function makeBoundedString(minLength: number, maxLength: number) {
  return class BoundedString extends ValueObject<BoundedStringProps> {
    private constructor(props: BoundedStringProps) {
      super(props);
    }

    get value() {
      return this.props.value;
    }

    public static create(props: BoundedStringProps): Result<BoundedString> {
      const guardRes = Guard.combine([
        Guard.againstNullOrUndefined(props.value, "value"),
        Guard.inRange(props.value?.length ?? 0, minLength, maxLength, "value"),
      ]);

      if (!guardRes.succeeded) {
        return Result.fail(guardRes.message);
      }

      return Result.ok(new BoundedString(props));
    }
  };
}
```

And then it would be used like:

```js
const MyValueObjectName = makeBoundedString(1, 100);
```

This works in the sense that MyValueObjectName is now a class with a bounded length but it's not recognised by typescript as a type and so assigning it to an interface without "typeof" doesn't work.

```js
const SomeEntityName = makeBoundedString(1, 100);

interface SomeEntityProps = {
 name: SomeEntityName; // Value not a type
}
```

Is there anyway I can achieve what I want with as little code as possible (ideally a one-liner)?

Answer (score 0):

This just isn't going to work without a `typeof`.

When you statically declare a class (like `class MyClass {}`), Typescript does some magic. It creates a type named `MyClass`, and a value called `MyClass`. The magic is that it seems like you have one thing, the class, that works in a value position and a type position.

But these are different things.

The value is the class constructor, the thing you call with `new` to create instances. And the type, then, is actually the type of the instances of that class. They are related, but they are different.

However, when you dynamically declare a class (like `return class ....`) this magic doesn't happen. Functions return values, period. And values cannot be used as types. If you want the type of a value you must use the `typeof` operator.

So, you could emulate it like:

```
const SomeEntityName = makeBoundedString(1, 100);
type SomeEntityName = typeof SomeEntityName
```

But I think that's the best you're going to get.